# Spring Roo 1.2.1 error: Suddenly doesn't recognize the Roo annotations

Tags: spring-roo

I have a roo project and suddenly it doesn't recognize the Roo annotations anymore. What do I have to do to fix that? I'm working on Spring STS 2.9.0 and using Spring Roo 1.2.1.

Errors in Roo console:

```
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.2:compile (default) @ infiniloja ---
[ERROR] The import org.springframework.roo.addon.jpa cannot be resolved
[ERROR] RooJpaActiveRecord cannot be resolved to a type
[ERROR] The import org.springframework.roo.addon.jpa cannot be resolved
[ERROR] RooJpaActiveRecord cannot be resolved to a type
.....
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.2:compile    (default) on project infiniloja: Compiler errors :
[ERROR] error at import org.springframework.roo.addon.jpa.activerecord.RooJpaActiveRecord;
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Review the pom.xml and the maven compiler logs.

Maybe you don't have the required dependency: roo-annotations.jar for the 1.2.1 version (take a look to your local m2 repository)

It happened to me once, due to the roo-annotations dependency, that maven couldn't download, when I changed from the 1.2 version to the 1.2.1 (besides, I had to modify the proxy settings that was the underlying reason, it was blocking the download)

Comment: Ok, I cleaned up my local maven repository (.m2/repository/) and everything is working fine!

Answer (score 0):

Right click the project name and select "Maven->Update Project...", then click OK to solve this problem.

The issue is that STS sometimes gets out of sync with Maven when you're using the Roo Shell. This tends to happen when you're setting up a project. Before running Update Project, I had no Maven jars on my project's STS classpath.